# Integrate opensearch prometheus exporter to Kubernetes/helm

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, opensearch, exporter

My Opensearch app runs in Kubernetes.

I found this OpenSearch exporter plugin:
https://github.com/aparo/opensearch-prometheus-exporter

to export metrics to prometheus.
Is there any option to integrate this solution to kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after you install plugins, You need Prometheus running on Kubernetes.

I recommend you install Prometheus-operator, which creates Prometheus service for you.

https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md

It includes the "ServiceMonitor" kind, which defines what "pod" under a "service" you would like to monitor.

After creating the "ServerMonitor" point to your Opensearch pod correctly, Prometheus will scape your metrics.

Comment: my concern is the "install plugins" part. there's no helm chart or no docker container with those plugins already installed. what is the best practice?
create your own docker image with those plugins installed?